# How to form a table with variable columns in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to make a table in a Django template with variable columns, and I've been trying to do so by using the following code:

Suppose I have headers like :

```
headers = ['date', 'a', 'b', 'c']
body = [{'date': '2015-10-16', 'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3},
        {'date': '2015-10-17', 'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6},
        ....]
```

As you can see headers correspond to keys of the body values.
So I've been trying to do that using **for** nested loops but, I failed.

```
<table >
    <thead>
      <tr>
         {% for th in headers %}
           <th>{{th}}</th>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for bd in body  %}
       <tr>
        {% for h in header  %}
         {% with h as key %}
         <td>{{bd.key}}</td>
         {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
       </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `{{bd.key}}` is not displaying. Any solution ? or I need to rework my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom template filter:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_dict_item(target_dict, key):
    return target_dict.get(key, '')
```

usage:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
         {% for th in headers %}
           <th>{{ th }}</th>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for bd in body  %}
       <tr>
        {% for h in header  %}
         {% with h as key %}
         <td>{{ bd|get_dict_item:key }}</td>
         {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
       </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was even having problems with headers containing spaces and your custom filter did it. cool.

Comment: I'm trying to use the same code but I am not shown any value for any `key`, though I get at the beginning of the rendered template `{‰ load custom_filter ‰}` - where `custom_filter.py` is the file containing the template custom filter. How could that be possible?